# How to call a method with python eve api?

Tags: python, api, eve

Let's say I want to execute a random function :

```
def compute_average( user)
```

This function will compute the average of few value and insert it into a user field. It's just an example.

How to call this function using the eve api?

I looked up the documentation but did not find anything.

Comment: I can't find that function in the source code... Where are you seeing that?

Comment: It's an example, I was talking about function you code in your api

Comment: I haven't used Eve, but I would look at the `settings.py` file in the Github example.

Comment: Does something like 'on post' exist ?
A function that is executed when the user posts something.

Comment: Eve just sits on top of Flask... There is a POST in Flask

Answer (score 2):

Since `Eve` derives from `Flask`, you can route pages the Flask way:

```
from flask import jsonify
from eve import Eve
app = Eve()

@app.route('/average/<user>')
def compute_average(user):
    return jsonify({user:47})

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Usage:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/average/joe
```

Result:

```
{
  "joe": 47
}
```

Comment: On running this I get error that says "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package". The shows up at the 3rd line: app=Eve(). Can you help me out? stuck for 3hrs.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11536764/5658251 couldn't figure from this..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, what you want is to run custom code before/after requests. To do that, you can use Event Hooks to set callbacks before/after request or database events. 
An example to run your `compute_average` before any `GET` to `users` resource:

```
def compute_average(request, lookup) 
    # your code

app = Eve()
app.on_pre_GET_users += compute_average

app.run()
```

Your function parameters would change a little. As the [documentation](http://python-eve.org/features.html#event-hooks) states, callbacks to a specific resource receive the original `flask.request` object and the current `lookup` dictionary as arguments.

But you can perform `mongodb` queries in your code as usual if you need to retrieve documents to perform your calculations.
Check the documentation for more details.